# Streamlining a batch file calling a sql file

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, sqlcmd

We currently have a scheduler to run audits. This scheduler will call a batch file with a parameter, and the batch file calls a sql script (based on the parameter), which in turn calls a stored proc.

For each audit that runs, a separate batch file, and sql file. Best case I'd like to combine the two below files into 1 file that can be used for every new audit. Worst case I'd at least like to combine to get 1 file for each audit instead of two. Hopefully you all can help?

Batch File

```
@echo on
Echo Running SQL Command File for '%1' Data Audit Check

del "D:\Internal_Reports\%1\%1.txt"

sqlcmd -S localhost -d database -i "D:\DataAudit\%1.sql"  -s "," > D:\Temp\%1.csv -I -W -k 1

if %ERRORLEVEL% GTR 0 COPY "D:\Temp\%1.csv" "D:\Internal_Reports\%1\%1.txt"

if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 goto Error_1
echo No Errors
goto end

:Error_1
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 1 goto Error_2
echo No Errors
goto end

:Error_2
echo Errorlevel %ERRORLEVEL% 
set FileName=%1%2
echo Filename %FileName%
echo %ERRORLEVEL% > D:\ErrorLevel\%FileName%
EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
:end
```

SQL File

```
set NoCount on
DECLARE
@createdBy varchar(16),

@dataAuditBatchId int, 

@createdDtTm datetime

select 
@createdBy = 'AutomatedAudit'
exec CreateNewDataAuditBatch @createdBy, @dataAuditBatchId output

-- Content Scripts
exec specificAuditStoredProc @createdBy, @dataAuditBatchId
select * from vAuditErrors where JobName in ('specificAuditStoredProc')
:exit(select Case When Counter = 0 then 0 Else 1 End 'errorCode'
from (select CAST(Count(*) AS varchar(4)) AS Counter from vAuditErrors 
    where JobName in ('specificAuditStoredProc'))
CountTable
)
```

Comment: Which version of SQL?

Comment: Check my PowerShell suggestion below, if you're comfortable with Stored Procs and Batch scripting, powershell will be your new best friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be PowerShell in this case.   You can combine both worlds of Batch Scripting and direct access to SQL.

Copy the below code into a text file:  Audit.ps1

Create a File called:  AuditFile.txt, put your SpecificAuditProc names on each line.

Then in your batch scheduler run this:  "powershell -command "& c:\Audit.ps1 -name 'ProcName'"

Heres the code [Untested]:

```
       param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$name="")

$createdBy = "AutomatedAudit"

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=LOCALHOST;Database=HT;Integrated     Security=True"
$SqlConnection.Open()  

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "[CreateNewDataAuditBatch]"
$SqlCmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure
$SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@createdBy", $creadtedBy)
$SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@dataAuditBatchId ")
$SqlCmd.Parameters["@dataAuditBatchId"].Direction = [system.Data.ParameterDirection]::Output
$SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
$dataAuditBatchId = $Command.Parameters["@dataAuditBatchId"].value
$SqlCmd.Dispose() 


$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "[$name]"
$SqlCmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure
$SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@createdBy", $creadtedBy)
$SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@dataAuditBatchId ", $dataAuditBatchId)
$SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
$SqlCmd.Dispose() 

$sqlcheck = @(Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "select * from vAuditErrors where JobName in ('$name')" -ServerInstance "LOCALHOST\HT")
if ($sqlcheck.Count -ne 0) {
$sqlcheck > D:\Internal_Reports\$name\$name.txt
$sqlcheck.Count >> D:\ErrorLevel\$name
}

$Connection.Close()
$Connection.Dispose()
```

Comment: i like the powershell idea. I think I need your help in modifying this a bit. In my head, this file would be called with a parameter. The parameter is the specific stored procedure to call. It appears as if this simply goes through all the files in a folder and executes each of them?

Comment: Edited to pass named parameter

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple problem to solve in pure batch ***PROVIDED*** you clarify a few points.

1. What is "%1" here? The database name perhaps?
2. Do you have just one `SQL file` and if not, what elements in the sample you posted need to be replaced for different databases?

(sorry - this isn't really an **answer** per se, but I'll make some (i hope, useful) comments on your btch as posted. The SO `comment` facility really doesn't suit here...

```
@echo on
Echo Running SQL Command File for '%1' Data Audit Check

del "D:\Internal_Reports\%1\%1.txt"

sqlcmd -S localhost -d database -i "D:\DataAudit\%1.sql"  -s "," > D:\Temp\%1.csv -I -W -k 1
```

OK: so in all probability, `%1` id the database name. So - why `-d database` and not `-d %1` ??

Why the `> D:\...` and not '-o D:...` ??

```
if %ERRORLEVEL% GTR 0 COPY "D:\Temp\%1.csv" "D:\Internal_Reports\%1\%1.txt"
```

Ack! The fail-to-fail scenario in all its glory! Most commonly, you'd get ERRORLEVEL 0 from the `sqlcmd` **BUT** `COPY` can change ERRORLEVEL. If the `COPY` succeeds, then ERRORLEVEL will be 0, but if `COPY` fails, `ERRORLEVEL` would be non-zero and that's the value that will be used by the steps following...

```
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 goto Error_1
echo No Errors
goto end

:Error_1
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 1 goto Error_2
echo No Errors
goto end
```

You could arrive at `:error_2` by simply executing

```
if errorlevel 2 goto error2
```

directly after the `SQLCMD` is executed (means "If errorlevel is 2 **OR GREATER**")

```
:Error_2
echo Errorlevel %ERRORLEVEL% 
set FileName=%1%2
echo Filename %FileName%
echo %ERRORLEVEL% > D:\ErrorLevel\%FileName%
EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
:end
```

Suddenly an unexplained `%2` appears...?

Comment: %1 is the specific stored proc being called. This is taken from a process currently in place, and I'm trying to impove it. As for %2, artifact from a previous iteration?

Comment: and as for the different sql files...honestly I'm not sure. I've looked at several and they seem to be different but mostly on the level of (most likely) made by different people. Certainly databases are different. But I believe if that is the only difference, it could be passed in with a parameter?